# gcloud instance in a project generates 403 error- for fast.ai setup

Tags: instance, gcloud

I'm trying to create an instance inside a project using the commands I've been given for setting things up for fastai using Ubuntu 2004 in windows 10.

```
gcloud compute instances create $INSTANCE_NAME         \
    --zone=$ZONE                                       \
    --image-family=$IMAGE_FAMILY                       \
    --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release      \
    --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE                     \
    --accelerator="type=nvidia-tesla-p100,count=1"     \
    --machine-type=$INSTANCE_TYPE                      \
    --boot-disk-size=200GB                             \
    --metadata="install-nvidia-driver=True"            \
    --preemptible
```

The above request creates an error:

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:                                                       - The user does not have access to service account 'service-############@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.  User: 'emailaddress@gmail.com'.  Ask a project owner to grant you the iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account

I'm kind of surprised I don't have access, as on the iam page, my email address from emailaddress@gmail.com is the owner (edit: on the iam page my email address is listed as the owner). The active account through gcloud auth list is emailaddress@gmail.com. I tried adding --impersonate-service-account withservice-#########@computer-system.iam.gserviceaccount to create the image, but that was [403] forbidden with explanation: Make sure the account that's trying to impersonate it has access to the service account itself and the "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator" role.

even from the https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/cli page, these are expected parameters. I can create an image from https://console.cloud.google.com/home/ but I don't know how to modify the accelerator or a couple other settings

There is a warning it creates, but I am fairly certain how to solve this issue: found in the fast.ai forum files to add billing to the account. Only added for completeness since I haven't changed it yet.
WARNING: Some requests generated warnings:                                                                               - Disk size: '200 GB' is larger than image size: '50 GB'. You might need to resize the root repartition manually if the operating system does not support automatic resizing. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd for details

edit in response to the comment:
Without the impersonation flag I received the same error.
With impersonating the @computer-system.iam.gservice I got:

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Error 403 (Forbidden) - failed to impersonate [service-392038697283@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com]. Make sure the account that's trying to impersonate it has access to the service account itself and the "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator" role.

so I added the serviceAccountTokenCreator role to that and I got

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Error 403 (Forbidden) - failed to impersonate [service-392038697283@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com]. Make sure the account that's trying to impersonate it has access to the service account itself and the "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator" role.

I'm giving these roles time limits as I think I just need to create the instance and that should be enough, but I'm unable to create the instance

edit: as of 09 July 2020, I tried installing Ubuntu 18.04[from this FastAI forum thread](https://forums.fast.ai/t/platform-gcp/27375/717?u=profturtle) which helped with a previous error but added nothing to the current issue. I tried going from wsl-2 to wsl-1 which also didn't work. While I would thoroughly suggest trying to suggestions in the comments I just went with a different service.

Comment: you shoud add compute.instances.setServiceAccount permission on that service account. To make this work, grant the iam.serviceAccountUser role to your service account(https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#the_serviceaccountuser_role) but you said that you can not open the I AM page, what is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: I was able to log into the iam page, I tried to edit the post to avoid that misunderstanding. I also added the errors from to the command with impersonating the gserviceaccount and without the first time the gserviceaccount had a permission

Comment: Please add Service Account Token Creator and Service Account User to your user and you need to give compute engine permissions to the service account [https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#compute-engine-roles] in order to create the instances.Also check the IAM Service Account Credentials API is enabled in the project.